# Debian installation from USB stick

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I have copied Debian ISO to USB stick and tried to boot system from it but the system starts with a grub screen like this image :
[image]

but when i use virtual box it shows me menu to select install and graphical install etc. What should i do now, i am new to Linux. My system is Intel "i7" with windows 10 on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install **debian** (and others linux distributions ) it's recommended to use `win32diskimager` as described [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en):

> The [win32diskimager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) utility can be used under other operating systems to copy the image.
>
> **Important**
> The image must be written to the whole-disk device and not a partition, e.g. /dev/sdb and not /dev/sdb1. Do not use tools like unetbootin which alter the image.

You can visit the official website of [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Unetbootin) to get more informations , because the grub-rescue appear after a failed installation of Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I used win32diskimager and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Windows you can use [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
to make a debian usb installation media from the iso that you have or download the latest version.